# Autocomplete JQuery reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am working with Struts 2, jsp, js and Jquery.

I have a little question about the autocomplete with Jquery.

Jquery version : 1.6
Autocomplete : 2.4.4.

I have two inputs (country and locality).
When i select a country with the autocomplete, i set the country code in a hidden input.

The locality must match only the country code (Like BE, LU, ...) of the selected country.

In JQuery, i added the "on('change')" event on the hidden input.
I trigger the change when i select the country.

At the page load and on each change on the country code, i set the autocomplete on the input like this :

E.g : i selected Germany and search for Frankfurt.

```
function setSuggestLocation(){
    // Add auto-completion
    var location = $("#labelLocationId"); 
    var countryCodeSelected = ($("#countryCode").val() != '' ? '?option=' + $("#countryCode").val() : '');
    var urlToAction = "myAction.action" + countryCodeSelected;

    location.autocomplete(urlToAction, {
        minChars: 2,
        onItemSelect: function(item) {
            $("#locationCode").val(item.data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

I send to my action (in the url), the autocomplete parameter "q" (= text) and the country code.

I can get the params in my action and i can select the city i want in the web page.

But if I change X times the country and i change the location in the autocomplete, the action will be call X times i changed the country code.

E.g

- 1) Select DE and a city.
- 2) Select BE. The action will be called for DE and for BE. I can see
  the city(cities) I found for DE previously.

I think the error is where i reset the autocomplete to the input but not sure.

I try to call .autocomplete("close"), .autocomplete("destroy") but i got errors.

Thanks in advance for your repsonses.

Comment: Mmm, could you post more code and we can work it out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the code.

Comment: Are you calling this function more than once?

Comment: No i only call the function at page load and on change on country code :
.on("change", function() {
  setSuggestLocation();  
 });
Thank you for your response.

Comment: So "yes" with the "and on change on country code" portion which is the issue at hand, it gets called multiple times thus adding a new event handler each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking the problem lies around setting up the autocomplete. Perhaps you can use this code to set the url when it changes.

```
// Getter
var source = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ] );
```

So in your instance the code would be

```
   $( "#location" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", myaction.action?param1=countryCode; );
```

Comment: Thank your for you response. I already try this solution but i get the error "can't assign to properties of (new String("source")): not an object".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark, i have added `$("#labelLocationId").unbind();` to remove previous handler and now it's works !

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, I namespace the stuff with `myApp` but that is easy to understand, then set the country code parameters when needed:

```
var myApp = myApp || {
  baseURL: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/base/getCitiesSuggestion.action",
  location: {},
  locationSelector: "#labelLocationId",
  countryCodeSelected: "",
  urlToAction: "",
  countryCodeSelector: "#countryCode",
  locationCodeSelector: "#locationCode",
  countryCode: jQuery(this.countryCodeSelector),
  setCountry: function() {
    this.countryCodeSelected = (this.countryCode.val() != '' ? '?option=' + this.countryCode.val() : '');
    this.urlToAction = this.baseURL + this.countryCodeSelected;
  },
  setSuggestLocation: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.location = $(this.locationSelector);
    this.location.autocomplete(me.urlToAction, {
      minChars: 2,
      onItemSelect: function(item) {
        $(me.locationCodeSelector).val(item.data);
      }
    });
  }
};


// set stuff up
myApp.setCountry();
// set the autocomplete (once only)
myApp.setSuggestLocation();

///some code here.....
// changed country, set it again:
myApp.setCountry();
```

This avoids binding and unbinding which simply slow things down.